# website content wrapper with elastic layout

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a problem with my website when I am displaying the content sometimes it overlaps the footer and the wrapper does not change the size based on the content size, because I have set it to an absolute value. So I should search for an "elastic" option to solve this problem I have been searching online finding anything, so I am a bit lost. How can I set the height of the wrapper so that the text is fully included and the page is long enough to include it without making it overlap the footer without using an absolute value?

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/bf5Tt/) is the jsfiddle of the problem. The css code of the wrapper is the following:

```
.wrapper {
    height: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto -142px; /* the bottom margin is the negative value of the footer's height */
}
```

Comment: Hi @softwareplay, I just edited your question. It would be awesome if you would try to write in a better English next time. While you are clearly a non-native speaker (me too) and making mistakes is nothing bad or wrong, you mainly used short forms (e.g. 've instead of have) and did not use a proper capital letter at the beginning of a sentences. I am sure that you could also do that and it is not a matter of insufficient English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give height:auto !important to your wrapper class. So below will what wrapper class look like..

```
.wrapper {
    height: auto !important;
    margin: 0 auto -142px; /* the bottom margin is the negative value of the footer's height */
    overflow:auto;
}
```

and if possible try to put footer outside the wrapper. That actually worked for me.

Here is the updated fiddle.

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bf5Tt/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you need to put div at the end of .wrapper, let's call it #push

```
<style type="text/css">
.wrapper { margin: 0 auto -142px; }
#push { height: 142px; }
</style>
<div class="wrapper">
<!-- some content here -->
    <div id="push"> </div>
</div>
```

and now wrapper is higher by 142px, so overlapping footer will cover #push instead of actual content.

Comment: no i need the wrapper to be long enough to contain the full text. It is not a problem, of the footer, i'm sorry, maybe i wasn't clear in my question, it is a problem of the wrapper not being elastic to contain the different size of content it has to contain. it is a problem of measurement, it shouldn't be absolute, but it should follow the lenght of the text..Am i clear now?

Comment: Now I understand that wrapper is not stretching to the size of content inside. Maybe change height to min-height in css .wrapper {}

Answer (score 0):

Try with these style changes

```
.wrapper {
    height: 500px; // remove this
    margin: 0 auto; 
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/39james/HZ6mM/)